# Invalid JSON Response - C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller, datatable

I am currently implementing DataTables and cannot debug this issue I am having. I am trying to use ajax.reload(), and I get Invalid JSON Response. Included below is my code for loading data, which is called after create/update.

```
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/List",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.itemName + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.itemType + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.itemPurchased + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.itemSKU + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.itemSize + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.itemColor + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + "$"+ item.itemPrice + '</td>';
                html += '<td>
                            <a href="#" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.itemID + ')">Edit</a> 
                          | <a href="#" onclick="Delete(' + item.itemID + ')">Delete</a> 
                          | <a href="#" onclick="return getsell(' + item.itemID + ')">Sell</a>
                        </td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
            $('#myTBODY').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
            
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

I attempted to check the Network tab on the Chrome Console, and this is what "List" returned:

```
[
     { 
        "itemID":76,
         "itemName":"Yeezy Boost 350",
         "itemType":"Shoe",
         "itemPurchased":"2021-02-03",
         "itemSKU":"F19961",
         "itemSize":"5",
         "itemPrice":220,
         "itemColor":"Blue"
     }, 

     { 
        "itemID":82,
         "itemName":"Yeezy Boost 350",
         "itemType":"Shoe",
         "itemPurchased":"2021-02-09",
         "itemSKU":"F19962",
         "itemSize":"5",
         "itemPrice":220,
         "itemColor":"Red"
     }, 

     { 
        "itemID":83,
         "itemName":"Yeezy Boost 350",
         "itemType":"Shoe",
         "itemPurchased":"2021-02-09",
         "itemSKU":"F19962",
         "itemSize":"5",
         "itemPrice":220,
         "itemColor":"Red"
     }, 

     { 
        "itemID":84,
         "itemName":"Yeezy Boost 350",
         "itemType":"Shoe",
         "itemPurchased":"2021-02-10",
         "itemSKU":"F19961",
         "itemSize":"5",
         "itemPrice":220,
         "itemColor":"Black"
     }, 

     { 
        "itemID":89,
         "itemName":"Yeezy Boost 350",
         "itemType":"Shoe",
         "itemPurchased":"2021-02-09",
         "itemSKU":"F19961",
         "itemSize":"5",
         "itemPrice":220,
         "itemColor":"Black"
     }, 

     { 
        "itemID":90,
         "itemName":"Yeezy Boost 350",
         "itemType":"Shoe",
         "itemPurchased":"2021-02-09",
         "itemSKU":"F19961",
         "itemSize":"5",
         "itemPrice":220,
         "itemColor":"Black"
     }, 

     { 
        "itemID":91,
         "itemName":"Yeezy Boost 350",
         "itemType":"Shoe",
         "itemPurchased":"2021-02-09",
         "itemSKU":"F19961",
         "itemSize":"5",
         "itemPrice":220,
         "itemColor":"Black"
     } 
 ]
```

I know that this is a valid JSON, but I just cannot grasp what it is I am doing wrong. I have tried everything on the official DataTables site, and am just stumped. Please let me know if I need to include something else (my List code, my html, etc), and I do apologize if I am not posting this properly.

Edit: Home Controller

```
public JsonResult List() // lists all inventory
{
    return Json(invDB.ListAll(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Edit: ListAll function

```
public List<Inventory> ListAll()
{
    List<Inventory> lst = new List<Inventory>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cd))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SelectItem", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            lst.Add(new Inventory
            {
                itemID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["itemID"]),
                itemName = rdr["itemName"].ToString(),
                itemType = rdr["itemType"].ToString(),
                itemPurchased = rdr["itemPurchased"].ToString(),
                itemSKU = rdr["itemSKU"].ToString(),
                itemSize = rdr["itemSize"].ToString(),
                itemColor = rdr["itemColor"].ToString(),
                itemPrice = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["itemPrice"])
            });
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

This is an image of my Network, the "List" returns what I sent above (the JSON I know is valid). I cannot find anything in network that explains the reasoning for invalid data.
[image]

Comment: Hello there, 

You need to post your code from your controller which is doing the manipulation of JSON. From what I see it is a GET Method, your controller is called Home and the action you are invoking is called List.
Moreover, we would need more details as regards the whole part such as what response are you getting when you go to the Network section in your Debugger ?

Comment: Hi Oris, I edited it to include the controller code, the function it invokes, and what my Network response looks like.

Comment: If you try doing it with a POST instead of a GET type request ?

Comment: Try removing the charset. - contentType:"application/json"

Comment: I tried changing type to POST, no luck.

Comment: I also tried removing ;charset=utf-8 and have the same issue. Thank you both thus far for the help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Here is some info as regards the ajax.reload(), https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()